# Date-Time in Qt

Tags: c++, linux, windows, qt, datetime

I am able to get File's access time, create time and read time stored as quint64(ULONGLONG).
I get this into Windows FILETIME structure.
Now I want to get the date-time in Qt equivalent code, so that it can be used in other OS also(cross-platform). I don't want to use the Windows specific code, my main aim is to run the code on both Windows and Linux.
How can I get this quint64 or FILETIME structure data to be converted into QDateTime or any Qt equivalent code?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Construct a `QFileInfo` object for your file and use its `created()`, `lastModified()` and `lastRead()` methods to get `QDateTime` values.